# Webpack bundles tests (enzyme / jest) in the production env

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

I have issue with Webpack building production bundle with test files + test libs included.

In this case it is Enzyme and Jest which we use.

Webpack version 3.10.0

Webpack.build.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function() {
  return {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: [
            /node_modules/,
            /__snapshots__/,
            /test-util/,
          ],
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'isomorphic-style-loader'
            },
            {
              loader: 'css-loader'
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader'
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin(),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
        }
      }),
    ]
  }
};
```

Here is the file structure
[image]

I have tried to workaround the issue by placing Enzyme as external resource in webpack.

```
externals: {
  'enzyme': 'enzyme',
  'enzyme-adapter-react-16': 'enzyme-adapter-react-16',
}
```

That does exclude it from build but (it is workaround) it still builds the snapshot files
[image]

I have tried to make "test" regex of babel-loader more specific and exclude test files but it failed.

This is new project and I spent whole day trying to make it bundle only what is necesary. Drained all of my know-how, my google know-how and know-how of the poeple I know or I work with. Hope that SO will be smarter :)

Comment: Any luck figuring this out? Thanks!

Comment: Still happening as of today and seems like there's no answer somewhere